# Can two user profiles on a single PC have their individual progression in shared games?

Tags: windows-10

I recently built a gaming PC. I have two M.2 slots installed: one is for the OS, and one is for games (both are 1 TB). The main user has several games installed (GTA, Warzone, Apex, Assassin's Creed Valhalla, etc.).

My question is: can I create a new user and still access these game from the M.2?
Different in-game progression would be needed. My main concern is that if it isn't possible I will have to download the games in the user account again and it would take me double the space per game.

Ideal situation:
User 1 and User 2 have different user profiles on the computer. The games are the same but progression would be different.

Is this possible?

---

PC Specs:

- TUF Gaming x570 Pro WIFI
- AMD Ryzen 9 5900x
- GeForce RTX 3080
- 2x WD Black SN750 M.2 2280 1TB
- Windows 10 Professional

Comment: Basically you want to know if two users would be to have their own windows accounts, but load the same game (from the same files) will they have different savegames?

Comment: yes, exactly! and how would I do it?

Comment: What platform are you using to manage the games? (Steam, Epic, etc.)

Comment: ^ Sorean's question is important because there might be additional instructions to tell the platform to install the game globally (all users) rather than locally (current user).